# How much contact did Avraham and Yitzchak have after the akeidah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, family-members, binding-of-isaac

The akeidah was a traumatic event for both Avraham and Yitzchak.  Immediately after they appear to go their separate ways.  After Sarah's death Avraham arranges a marriage for his son, which could have been done entirely by proxy (he sends Eliezer, who comes back with Rivka, who marries Yitzchak -- but Avraham is not mentioned as being there).  The next time Avraham and Yitzchak appear together in the torah text is when Yitzchak and Yishmael come to bury their father.

How much contact did Avraham and Yitzchak have after the akeidah?  Were the two distant, or was Avraham an active grand-parent, or something in between?  Did Avraham ever meet Yaakov and Eisav?

This question was prompted by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22233/472) about Avraham (not) seeing Eisav's sin.

Comment: See the answers to the question here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/why-did-rivka-consult-shem-and-not-avraham-or-yitzchok/  - there are opinions that say that Rivkah when to Avraham, or they explain why she didn't. This seems to indicate that he was close enough that she could have gone to him

Comment: crossposted: https://judaism.codidact.com/q/278321

Answer (score 3):

I'd heard Rabbi Ephraim Buchwald comment that after the Akeida, the relationship between Avraham and Yitzchak was somewhat -- distanced.

Comment: Did he explain why?